# Minimize the sum of three column-maximums of K rows

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

I've been struggling with how to improve on what I think is an `O(n^3)` procedure.

The task is: given N three-element tuples, choose K of them that minimise the sum of the maximums of each tuple element as a group. Constraints: 1 ≤ K ≤ N ≤ 2000, 1 ≤ tuple_element ≤ 10^9. For example, given:

```
{1, 2, 2}
{2, 1, 3}
{2, 2, 2}

K = 2
```

the choices could be:

```
Tuples 1 & 2
sum(max(1,2), max(2,1), max(2,3))
= 7

Tuples 1 & 3
sum(max(1,2), max(2,2), max(2,2))
= 6

Tuples 2 & 3
sum(max(2,2), max(1,2), max(3,2))
= 7
```

So the result is tuples 1 & 3 with sum 6.

My proposed procedure:

Consider tuples as `{A, B, C}`. Sort by A ascending. For each tuple we consider as the `k`th item in a combination, since A is increasing, it is also fixed as the current A in relation to the new combination. Since any new tuple will have an equal or larger A, we can ignore A in the following discussion.

From the previous list of tuples for `(k-1)`, if they have a B equal to or lower than the current B, we would like to pick the one with the lowest C, call it C', which results in the tuple, `(B, max(C, C'))`.

From the previous tuple list for `(k-1)`, if they have a B higher than the current B: (1) if they have an equal or lower C, we'd like the tuple with the lowest B, call it B', which results in the new tuple, `(B', C)`; (2) if they have a higher C (so both a higher B and a higher C), call it C', we'd like the tuple with the lowest sum (B' + C'), which results in the (possibly) new tuple, `(B', C')`.

We add the new tuple to the tuple list for `k` if that list has less than `k` items or the tuple's B or C is lower than any currently there.

While we have more than `k` items in the list for `k`, remove any tuple dominant to the new tuple (i.e., where both B and C are equal or larger).

Answer (score 0):

The min bound (most optimal solution if exist) is subject to the following condition:

Min bound {A, B, C} = A, B, C such that:

- A = K-th A when sorted by A
- B = K-th B when sorted by B
- C = K-th C when sorted by C

Thus, one can start from min bound {A, B, C} subject to the above condition and continually increase A, B, C until K set is found that satisfies `all set s in K is a subset of {A, B, C}`.

Subset definition:

```
{a, b, c} is subset of {A, B, C} iff a <= A and b <= B and c <= C
```

Dynamic programming condition:

- `NSet(An, B, C) = NSet(A, B, C) + NSet(A+1..An, B, C)`
- `NSet(A, Bn, C) = NSet(A, B, C) + NSet(A, B+1..Bn, C)`
- `NSet(A, B, Cn) = NSet(A, B, C) + NSet(A, B, C+1..Cn)`

Note that NSet(A, B, C) is actually NSet(1..A, 1..B, 1..C). It's shortened for readability.

NSet is the number of set. The algorithm should stop when `NSet(A, B, C) >= K` and all `sum({A, B, C}next)` is less than `sum({A, B, C})`.

An, Bn, Cn is the next value of A, B, and C respectively. Note even though the problem statement says that tuple value is from 1 to 10^9, there can only be 2000 distinct values of A, B, and C.

Once A, B, C is found just pick K tuple randomly that satisfies tuple is subset of {A, B, C}.

The worst case is still O(N^3) but in practice it should find a solution quickly since we build from the minimum bound and incrementally expand from there. Also, since N is 2000, N^3 is about 8,000,000,000 which can be computed fairly quickly in modern CPU.

Comment: The answer states, "An, Bn, Cn is the next value of A, B, and C respectively." Could you please clarify how the "next value" is chosen? If we have 100 duplicates of value X in A, when X is the "next value," how do we know which tuple to add to NSet, or does "next value" mean we add all 100 duplicates (all tuples where A=X) at once in the next step of the algorithm?

Comment: Next value is distinct, so if we have 100 duplicate value it count as 1 distinct value.

Comment: So for example let's say you have these tuples:
{1, 2, 2}
{3, 1, 3}
{3, 2, 2}
Next value of A = 1 is A = 3

Comment: So using the example above, let's say we're currently at {A, B, C} = {1, 2, 2}

NSet(An, B, C) = NSet(A, B, C) + NSet(A+1..An, B, C)

Will translate into:

NSet(3, 2, 2) = NSet(1, 2, 2) + 1

Why 1 because there is one set that satisfies NSet(2..3, 2, 2) which is {3, 2, 2} only

Comment: Note that even though {3, 1, 3} is a duplicate of A {3, 2, 2} it doesn't satisfy the predicate that we're solving so it is not counted

Comment: I get it now, thanks for explaining. That's an interesting way to look at the problem. I'm still hoping for better than O(n^3) in the worst case, though.